# Gensim's Document similarity can be used as supervised classification?

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, text-processing, gensim

Gensim has this document similarity feature which when inputted a query document, it outputs the similarity of that particular document with all the documents it has in its index

1. Can this be used like an "approximate" version of supervised classification?
2. I know gensim's word2vec uses Deep Learning, is this involved during the above step?

Comment: yes given that you have annotated data to train a post-word2vec classifier, then you can simply use the document vectors as features for your classifier.